# How to use a variable created inside the $(document).body function

Tags: jquery

I want to use the value of optionValue variable created inside the $(document).ready function. I keep getting "undefined" when I attempt to use the variable on the line as depicted on the code:

```js
var optionValue;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dropdownList').on('change', function() {
    var optionVal = $(this).val();
    var optionValue = $('#dropdownList option[value="' + optionVal + '"]').val();
    // selectedlga = $("#dropdownList option:selected").text();
    alert("Selected Option Text: " + optionValue);
  });
});

var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('data/lgacapital.geojson', {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

    var str = "<button id='zoomTo" + feature.properties.CAPITAL.replace(/ /g, '');
    str += "' class='form-control btn btn-primary attraction'>";
    str += feature.properties.CAPITAL + "</button>";

    var str = "<h4>" + optionValue + "</h4><hr>"; // OPTIONVALUE IS THE VARIABLE        
    return L.marker(latlng).bindPopup(str);
  }
});

geojsonLayer.addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: Remove the `var` in front of `optionValue` in the doc.ready handler, as you're redefining the variable within that scope. However it's worth noting that globals are not good practice and should be avoided. in addition, that variable is only set after the `change` event fires. As the `geojsonLayer` is being created when the page loads the value will *always* be undefined. I'd suggest moving that logic within the `change` event handler (or at least putting it in a function which is called from there). Then your scope issue becomes moot as you can pass the data as an argument to the function.

Comment: `var optionValue = $('#dropdownList option[value="' + optionVal + '"]').val();` ...as well as what Rory said, this whole line makes no sense and isn't needed. The result of it should be identical to what's in `optionVal` already. Think about it - you're getting the value of an option element, but you've selected the correct option element _based on its value_ (by using the `option[value=` selector). So, you already know the value, you don't have to get it again!

Comment: Anyway, instead of using a global which a) is usually not a very good practice and b) may not be populated yet by the time the pointToLayer function runs, it would be a lot simpler and easier to simply read the value of the dropdown directly inside that function. e.g. something like this: `var str = "<h4>" + $("#dropdownlist").val() + "</h4><hr>";` . And then you can get rid of `optionValue` and also remove the entire `$('#dropdownList').on('change', function() {` function - it's completely redundant.